# System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The Uri scheme is too long.'

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I working on a small project where I am trying to read a response from a websocket and trying to load it in xmlDoc for further operations.

The following are the snippet of my code, where i get the "System.UriFormatException". The response is of XMLType

```
        UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] buffer;

        buffer = encoder.GetBytes("<XML Response from a websocket>");

        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDoc.Load(xml);
```

Is there any way by which we could overcome the exception, or what am i doing wrong in this code.

Comment: Which line, exactly, raises the exception?

Comment: It look like you are trying to use the XML as a URL - is that correct? Or did you intend to use the [XmlDocument.LoadXml(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml?view=netframework-4.7.2) which takes XML as its argument?

Comment: xmlDoc.Load(xml) raises the exception

Comment: LoadXML fixes the problem. I had a URL implementation earlier and now i get the problem fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets visit the documentation

[XmlDocument.Load(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Load_System_String_)

> Loads the XML document from the specified URL.

```
xmlDoc.Load(xml);
```

`xml` is not a *Url*

What you are most likely looking for is

[XmlDocument.LoadXml(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Loads the XML document from the specified string.